# Set an array parameter value using Hibernate console on Intellij14

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm using Hibernate Console provided by Intellij 14, which has been working great so far. Recently I've came across with a hql that needs String[] as a parameter value since it's going to be used in a 'IN' clause.

I couldn't find anywhere how to set this array on the parameters window as shown below:

[image]

I've tried so many different ways like separating by comma or between curly brackets.

I'm refusing to believe that Hibernate console doesn't allow me to do that. Has anyone faced the same situation?

Comment: How about `new String[] { "a", "b" }`, or that doesn't work either?

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt unfortunately it doesn't work too :(

Comment: I've been playing with it the past few minutes and can't seem to get it working too. Perhaps it is a bug :(. Btw, I don't know your use case but can't you just hardcode it to the query in this case (like `IN ("foo", "bar")`). If you're just trying to run some query from the console it shouldn't matter whether the query is correctly parametrized or not

Comment: It really doesn't work for `new String[] { "a", "b" }`, but it works in another way, see my answer below:)@Bohuslav Burghardt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried kinds of programming ways (like `["val1", "val2"]`, `new String[]{"a", "b"}` etc), they all didn't work, but there is another way, it is to specify separate parameter **as workaround** for this problem, and it works well.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value for `:CAMPAIGNS` in the Parameter window should be in the form `('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`.

Alternatively, when using the IntelliJ Query Console, you can provide array values in the query itself:

```
...from User us join us.campaignUsers as cus where cus.campaignUserPK.campaign.id in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

In modern versions of IntelliJ, you now get a prompt window to specify what value `:CAMPAIGNS` should be when you execute. Simply add the value for the string array:

[image]